# Swizzle the AppDelegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

I'm working on Framework which needs to be get the application life cycle events. I'm trying with **NotificationCenter** it fails under framework. So i decided to implement the **Method Swizzling** using obj c run time. The problem is the below code working fine as expected in **Emulator**. When i was running the Device it gets failed.

The good thing is Extended method is called and when call the original method, this gets failed with message

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)
```

Here is my code

```
IMP originalImplementation;

+ (instancetype)initWith:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier{
    Demo *instance = [[Demo alloc] init];
    [instance swizzlingLifeCycleMethods];
    return instance;
}

- (void)swizzlingLifeCycleMethods{

    //Prepare the injected class name to be injecting
    Class originalClass = NSClassFromString(@"AppDelegate");

    //Prepare the methods to swizzling
    SEL originalWillResignAction = @selector(applicationWillResignActive:);
    SEL extendedWillResignActive = NSSelectorFromString(@"extendedApplicationWillResignActive");

    //Get original method and method encoding
    originalResignMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalClass, originalWillResignAction);
    originalImplementation = method_getImplementation(originalResignMethod);
    const char *originalResignMethodEncoding = method_getTypeEncoding(originalResignMethod);

    //Add swizzling method into targetted class
    class_addMethod(originalClass, extendedWillResignActive, (IMP)extendedApplicationWillResignActive, originalResignMethodEncoding);

    //Swizzling the methods
    Method extendedResignMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalClass, extendedWillResignActive);
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalResignMethod, extendedResignMethod);
}

//Called at the time of user enters into background
void extendedApplicationWillResignActive(id self, SEL _cmd, va_list args1)
{
    //Implement our logic here

    //Call the original function after our stuff done
    ((void(*)(id, SEL, ...))originalImplementation)(self, _cmd, args1);
}
```

I'm using the Universal Framework build in my sample project to use this framework. Kindly let me know whats wrong with this.

Answer (score 1):

> Kindly let me know whats wrong with this.

I cannot run your code (it is incomplete), but the following probably contribute in some combination to your problems.

First the declaration of `applicationWillResignActive` is:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application;
```

however in your `extendedApplicationWillResignActive` function you have changed `UIApplication *` to `va_list`, this is wrong. There are cases where it may work, at it seems it may have for you in the simulator, but there are cases when it will blow up, as appears to have happened to your on your device (note here that the simulator runs x86 code, the device ARM code).

The obvious question here is why did you change the type of the argument?

Second you are bypassing writing a method and swizzling directly with (an incorrectly typed) C function. While not wrong *per se* it probably doesn't help you out.

Third you are attempting to add a method:

```
- (void)extendedApplicationWillResignActive:
```

to a class without any check that such a method does not already exist. This is unwise at best, how does your framework know that the application using it has not defined such a method? The likelihood may be small, but it is greater than zero, and is an unnecessary risk. That said this probably isn't a problem in your case (as you wrote the class you are swizzling so know there is no such existing method).

Finally you have hardwired the name of the class, `AppDelegate`, that you are swizzling. The application delegate could have a different name. Your `initWith:` method takes an argument `bundleIdentifier`, currently unused, so I'll assume this is an indication you intended to address this issue.

---

Let's see if we can help you fix this. What you are attempting to do here is *cross class swizzling*. To achieve this you can:

- Use the correct type for the target method/implementation function throughout;
- Write your replacement as a method; and
- Just replace the implementation of the targeted method without adding an new methods to the class

Here is your code with these changes. **This code is just being copied and edited in line, it has not be run, expect errors, take it as an outline ONLY.**

```
@implementation Demo
{

// define a typedef for the target method's implementation function
typedef void (*OriginalImpType)(id self, SEL selector, UIApplication *application);
// declare this static as it is private to this class
static OriginalImpType originalImplementation;

+ (instancetype)initWith:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier{
    Demo *instance = [[Demo alloc] init];
    [instance swizzlingLifeCycleMethods:bundleIdentifier];
    return instance;
}

- (void)swizzlingLifeCycleMethods:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier
{

    // Get the class for the application delegate
    Class originalClass = ... however you plan to do this using bundleIdentifier ...;
    // Get the swizzling class
    Class demoClass = [Demo class];

    // Prepare the methods to swizzling
    SEL originalWillResignAction = @selector(applicationWillResignActive:);
    SEL extendedWillResignActive = @selector(extendedApplicationWillResignActive:);

    // Get original method and save it
    Method originalResignMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(originalClass, originalWillResignAction);
    originalImplementation = (OriginalImpType)method_getImplementation(originalResignMethod);

    // Swizzling the method
    Method extendedResignMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(demoClass, extendedWillResignActive);
    method_setImplementation(originalResignMethod, method_getImplementation(extendedResignMethod));
}

// Called at the time of user enters into background
- (void) extendedApplicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //Implement our logic here

    //Call the original function after our stuff done
    originalImplementation(self, _cmd, application);
}

} // end of @implementation Demo
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks CRD, i've changed my new method implementation and it works.

- (void) quixxiApplicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    ((void(*)(id, SEL, UIApplication *))originalImplementation)(self, _cmd, application);
}